# value of variable not changing using useState Hook in React JS when implemented using onClick button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I implemented a nested ternary operator to render one of 3 things based on condition, it is for the quiz app, one renders the results, on the quiz and one has the option to choose the genre of the quiz.

I defaulted it in such a way that the genre selection defaults, and when the selection is made, clicking the button calls a function that sets the genre's value and changes the variable which essentially changes the ternary operator to change the rendering component.

The problem is genreContainer variable isn't changing from false to true, which is implemented in the function.

```
import { React, useState } from 'react'
import './quiz.css'
import { QuizData } from '../../data/QuizData'
import Result from '../result/Result'



const Quiz = () => {
    const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0);
    const [score, setScore] = useState(0);
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0);
    const [showResult, setShowResult] = useState(0);
    const [currentGenre, setCurrentGenre] = useState(0);
    let genreContainer = false;

    const changeQuestion = () => {
        updateScore();
        if (currentQuestion < QuizData[0].data[currentGenre].length - 1) {
            setCurrentQuestion(currentQuestion + 1);
            setSelected(0);
        }
        else {
            setShowResult(true);
        }

    }

    const genreSelection = () => {
        genreContainer = true;
        setCurrentGenre(selected - 1);
        setSelected(0);

    }

    const updateScore = () => {
        if (selected === QuizData[0].data[currentGenre][currentQuestion].answer) {
            setScore(score + 1)
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className='container'>
            {showResult ? (
                <Result score={score} totalScore={QuizData[0].data[currentGenre].length} />
            ) : (
                <>
                    {genreContainer ? (
                        <>
                            <div className="question">
                                <span id='question-number'>
                                    {currentQuestion + 1}.
                                </span>
                                <span id='question-txt'>
                                    {QuizData[0].data[currentGenre][currentQuestion].question}
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div className="option-container">
                                {QuizData[0].data[currentGenre][currentQuestion].options.map((option, i) => {
                                    return (
                                        <button className={`option-btn ${selected === i + 1 ? 'checked' : null}`}
                                            key={i}
                                            onClick={() => setSelected(i + 1)}
                                        >
                                            {option}
                                        </button>
                                    )
                                })}
                            </div>
                            <input type="button" value="Next" id='next-button' onClick={changeQuestion} />
                        </>
                    ) : (
                        <>
                            <div className="question">
                                <span id='question-txt'>
                                    Choose your genre of Quiz
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div className="option-container">
                                {QuizData[0].options.map((option, i) => {
                                    return (
                                        <button className={`option-btn ${selected === i + 1 ? 'checked' : null}`}
                                            key={i}
                                            onClick={() => {
                                                setSelected(i + 1);
                                            }}
                                        >
                                            {option}
                                        </button>
                                    )
                                })}
                            </div>
                            <input type="button" value="Select" id='next-button' onClick={genreSelection} />
                            
                        </>
                    )}
                    
                </>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
export default Quiz
```

here the genreContainer variable's value isn't changing when genreSelection function is called.

Comment: `setScore` is async

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is genreContainer variable isn't changing from false to true

Yes it is.  *But*, then you immediately update state.  Updating state triggers a re-render.  And what does the component do when it renders?  This:

```
let genreContainer = false;
```

If you want a value to persist across renders, there's a mechanism for that... *state*.  For example:

```
const [genreContainer, setGenreContainer] = useState(false);
```

And:

```
const genreSelection = () => {
    setGenreContainer(true);
    setCurrentGenre(selected - 1);
    setSelected(0);
}
```